# Weird bug generating text with only the first of several SVGs on a page

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have a page built in React that generates several plots in D3. The title text in the first plot, however, looks really ugly and distorted. Seen here:

[image: Text distortion]

Notice how all the other text is perfectly fine. Also the plots further down the page are also perfectly fine. It only affects the title of the first plot generated with exactly the same code. Taking away bold doesn't help. Here's the code for the title:

```
svg.selectAll('text.title').data(blueCoords).enter().append('text')
            .attr('x', blueCoords[0] + 2 + gap / 2)
            .attr('y', plotDisplace)
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .attr("font-family", '"Montserrat", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif')
            .attr("font-weight","bold")
            .text(chunkTitle)
```

Comment: Try `.attr('stroke', 'none')`

Comment: No dice :( Same result

Comment: There is insufficient code here to replicate the problem and therefore answering is difficult - but this sort of visual effect is generally due to re-appending text over existing text. Inspecting the page and seeing if many text elements overlap would confirm this. Sharing additional code may allow a concrete answer (you can strip axis, bar, scale code to keep things concise).

Comment: It would be useful if you copy the offending SVG (or relevant part of it) to your question.  Make sure what you post reproduces the problem.